# In-place upgrading repairing ownership of C:

Tags: windows, windows-10, permissions, windows-10-upgrade, ownership

I made the horrible mistake of claiming ownership of C: from `TrustedInstaller` and I'm not regretting it upon realizing that all Windows 10 apps are defunct. Reversing what I did is not solving the issue. I can't System Restore or do Startup Repair. Is an in-place upgrade going to fix this, or will I really have to reformat?

Comment: People seem to not like me proposing this app as an answer, so just as a comment - [Windows all in one Repair](http://www.tweaking.com/content/page/windows_repair_all_in_one.html) can fix that. Freeware version is sufficient. Follow all instructions, don't skip any.

Comment: Do you mean you're *now* regretting it?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, system rest seems to be a better solution than repair upgrade, which doesn’t need to download iso image file.

If you are using Windows 10 1703 version, Please go to Settings->Update & Security->Recovery->Reset this PC, note choose keep my files option.

If you are using 1607 or earlier version, I suggest to download 1703 iso image file from Microsoft website to upgrade system.
Regards